# How to tie bind and load methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Loaded content on the page to another page. If the information is read incorrectly, then you should use the bind () method to display a message about it. How to do it?

```
$("#result").load("university.html");
```

Comment: maybe an `if` statement: `if(result != null){// run code  here...}`

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing the two different `load()` functions in jQuery. There's an [event handler](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) which binds to the load event, and an [AJAX method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that requests content. Your question isn't exactly clear.

Comment: Is that an exercice or what? If not, please better explain expected behaviour

Comment: hm... But I have this task. I have used just bind to handle the error. Is it real?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if the request succeeded, you can use a callback function.

```
$("#result").load("university.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```